# Xcode installs multiple containing apps onto device when debugging/running iOS8 App Today Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios-app-extension

I have an iOS project that has several targets.  Each target also has an embedded Today Extension.

All my build schemes have been created automatically, and recently refreshed.

However, when I try to Debug/Run my Today Extension on the actual device, Xcode deploys multiple apps/extensions to the device, not just the one in the selected Scheme.

For example, if I select this scheme:

[image]

...then not only is BusCheckerTodayExtension, and its containing app installed to the device and run, but also BusCheckerUKTodayExtension, BusCheckerWESTTodayExtension and both of their containing apps too.

Is this a bug to be reported in XCode or is this some obscure build/dependency setting that I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was almost certainly a bug in Xcode and seems to be fixed in newer releases.